# Python задача на числа

Tags: python

Как прописать корректное условие?

```
max = 1000
result = 0
for i in range(0,max):
    if (i % 2 == 0 or i % 3 == 0) and (not i % 4 == 0):
        result += i
print(result)
```

Comment: в чем вопрос то?

Comment: как прописать условие корректно

Comment: "кратных 2 и 3" это "кратных 6"?

Comment: получается что кратное 6, одновременно число должно делиться на 2 и 3 и не делиться на 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> кратных 2 **и** 3

поэтому нужен `and` а не `or`:

```
(i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0)
```

Либо как сказал @AlexandrIvanov проверять кратность на `6`:

```
i % 6 == 0
```

---

```
not i % 4 == 0
```

Место `not` лучше использовать `!=`:

```
i % 4 != 0
```

В итоге получаем:

```
if i % 6 and i % 4 != 0:
```

в одну строку:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(0, max) if i % 6 == 0 and i % 4 != 0]))
```

или так:

```
print(sum(filter(lambda x: x % 6 == 0 and x % 4 != 0, range(0, max))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите, чтобы числа были кратны и 2, и 3 одновременно, например число 6, то вы должны вместо `or` написать `and`. Оператор `or` говорит программе, что числа должны быть либо кратны 2, например число 14, либо 3, например число 9. Короче говоря, код должен быть вот таким:

```
for i in range(0,max):
if (i % 2 == 0 and i % 3 == 0) and (not i % 4 == 0):
    result += i
```